# NE555 not working in monostable operation, but TLC555 works

Tags: 555

I tested out a monostable circuit using the TLC555 timer. I use a pot (0-500 kΩ) and a 100 μF capacitor. I used [this timer circuit](https://elonics.org/adjustable-auto-on-off-delay-timer-circuit-using-555/) as a reference. It worked fine at 9 V using the TLC555.

I replaced the timer with an [NE555](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A200/555ESTEK.pdf) and it does not work anymore. The only way the LED turns on is when the pot is at 0 Ω and the trigger is pressed. If I release the trigger the LED turns off immediately. If the pot is at 500 kΩ and the trigger is pressed the LED shines very dimly. If the trigger is released the LED turns off immediately.

Why is it working using the TLC555, and what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: shouldn't there be a decoupling capacitor on VCC?

Comment: Draw out the schematic showing how you have it connected.  There is a schematic editor built into the site.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added the capacitor and wow it seems to work now for now. Thank you very much I did not expect this.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat there is a link in my description where you can see the schematic. But I think it's just because of the decoupling capacitor.

Comment: Generally questions should be complete here.  I've looked at the circuit.

Comment: @cid There's usually a decoupling cap on the Control pin (5) as well, datasheet shows this as 0.01uF.

Comment: @GodJihyo, most 555 circuits I've ever seen don't fit that cap', rare to see it used.

Comment: The schematic you link to uses a 68K resistor and 470 uF capacitor for timing. If you've just replaced the 68K resistor with a 500K pot, you'll risk damaging the 555 when the pot's wound down to 0 ohms and the 555 enables it's DISCHG output (pin 7), as the pot' will connect DISCHG to the supply rail. Put a resistor in series with the pot' to give a minimum resistance. That's a common practice with adjustment pots. Value comes from your timing requirements but, say, 4K7 if you don't know what else (gives 2mA max. pull-up).

Comment: @TonyM Must be a lot more Muntzing going on out there than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MarcusMüller solved my problem thanks!

> shouldn't there be a decoupling capacitor on VCC